# redirect the user to a website by the code he typed in input

Tags: php, mysql

i want to creat a form with one input

```
    <form method="post">
        <div align="center">
                            <div class="error"></div>
                            <div class="iii">
            <div class="label">TUT number</div>
            <input type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'  pattern="\d*" class="iin" name="number"/>
            <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

        <div align="center">
            <input class="go" type="submit" value=" go" name="Submit" >
        </div>
    </form>
```

so if the user input is for example " `4584` " will redirect him to APPLE website, if the input is " `5488` " redirect to google.

for sure i can't use only if statment because i want to `add/edit/delete` the links and codes!

i tried to search hard but didn't found how.

regards.

Comment: I bet there is a good logic why 4584 means Apple and 5488 is Google, care to explain it?

Comment: @Andreas it's just an example i want to do some apps tutorials and with every tut i want to give a code so if the user put the code in the input will redirect them to the app url .

Comment: *"i can't use only if statment because i want to add/edit/delete the links and codes"*, that does not prevent you from using an if-statement. Also could you provide the PHP you currently have?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek ok but it hard to edit the code every time i need to add a new link and code :)

Comment: @JoseLuis That's based on how you do this. For example it would make sense to do `if(isset($_POST['number'])){ .. }` because trying to grab it's value. Also add/edit/delete should be in in a different location in terms of code, there shouldn't be any dependencies.

Comment: So you want to build a page where the user goes to and enters a code that has no relation more than an arbitrary number. The user needs to remember the codes instead of 'apple.com'. Why? If I would want to go to apple I don't want to go to your page and try to remember a code and then get linked to apple. I would type "apple.com" in the browser. Most likely I only need to type "app" and it will suggest apple.com making it one char less than your four digit code. Why????

Comment: @Andreas it's just an idea i want to do i can't tell you everything about it and for sure i wont creat all this code to go to my website then type the code the redirect to apple.com :) i know that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the links saved in the database you can simply fetch the row with the given code and use a redirect of any kind to redirect the user to the target URL. The code will look like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT url FROM links WHERE code = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['number']));
if (!$row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    /* not found */
} else {
    $url = $row['url'];
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit;
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: thank you but how to make it work with the form above?

Comment: @JoseLuis That is the pseudo code which will read a row from the database based on the input `$_POST['number']`. When an entry is found a redirect is created with the `Location:` header. If no row is found you can show an info message and show the HTML form again.

Comment: i gor this error messages
Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in test.php on line 4

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in test.php on line 4

Comment: didnt work !!, i just created a connection file and this file. i doesnt work i got the same error

Comment: @JoseLuis When you get the same error message then you haven't saved the `PDO` object in the variable `$dbh`. You can rename the variable as you like but the `prepare()` method has to be called on this create `PDO` object.

Answer (score -1):

Use cookies for every user and add a cookie value each time you add a new website to the list. like

> $_COOKIE["Apple"] = "4584"
>
> $_COOKIE["Google"] = "5488"
>
> $_COOKIE["Ibm"] = "1234"    //this can be any new wesite and code you want

Comment: it's wont work because my problem is i wont to edit the php code every time i want to add a new webiste, i use a database for this

Comment: then why don't you copy database website list to cookie array

Comment: @Ganesh What have cookies to do with the question?